# Wrong OG image when sharing to Facebook despite FB Debugger displaying correctly

Tags: image, facebook-opengraph

I just added an OpenGraph image to a site I'm working on and using the FB Debugger the info retrieves the correct image, however when sharing the url I still see default images being displayed (there was no specified OG image before). Is there something I'm missing here? The site uses a custom Python based framework and image is served via gzip from an Amazon EC2 instance, if that would affect the output in any way.

Comment: Have you tried "Fetch New Scrape information" in the FB debugger?

Comment: Ah, yes tried that as well.

Comment: Any other caching or CDN involved?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is not with your website. 
Facebook takes some time to refresh images inside facebook.com even though you can see the changes on Facebook Debug Tool.

In order to view your new image inside Facebook you can do two things:

1. Manipulate a little the URL you are trying to share, this way
   Facebook will fetch the open graph data again.
2. Just give it some
   time, it will be refreshed after a few hours.

Comment: We've been waiting for 3 weeks :) I doubt this is the problem, but will give it another try and change the urls.

Comment: And of course it works now after updating the url... Thanks for the tip Alexandros!

Comment: for me, one more help: go here : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ and and click "Scrap again" button

Answer (score -1):

There are three way to change your image you need to clear the

1) Manually clear facebook catch using the https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ facebook tool

2) Add version code end of the url like ?v=1

3) write the GraphAPI code from when you click on the share button it will clear the facebook page cache.